# when i test this code , it was not echo `8 > 3`?

Tags: php

when i test this code , it was not echo `8 > 3`  (it's will echo `1 = 1`)?

i check my code are correct but why not echo real result?

```
<?PHP
        $number = 8;
        if ($number = '0')
            {
               echo $number." = 0";
            }
        elseif ($number = '1')
            {
               echo $number." = 1";                
            }
        elseif ($number = '2')
            {
               echo $number." = 2";               
            }
        else
            {
               echo $number." > 3";               
            }
?>
```

Comment: replace the '=' with '==' if you want to compare two things

Comment: In the curren code  if condition is assigning value not checking so replace the '=' with '== for comparing strings

Comment: You've made your $number, an int, check against a string. Also you use only one `=` where you need two `==` http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php

Answer (score 4):

Comparison in PHP is done via the `==` operator, not the `=` operator.

```
<?PHP
        $number = 8;
        if ($number == '0')
            {
               echo $number." = 0";
            }
        elseif ($number == '1')
            {
               echo $number." = 1";                
            }
        elseif ($number == '2')
            {
               echo $number." = 2";               
            }
        else
            {
               echo $number." > 3";               
            }
?>
```

Comment: Not only PHP, this is done with `==` in pretty much every language.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<?PHP
    $number = 8;
    if ($number == 0)
        {
           echo $number." = 0";
        }
    elseif ($number == 1)
        {
           echo $number." = 1";                
        }
    elseif ($number == 2)
        {
           echo $number." = 2";               
        }
    else
        {
           echo $number." > 3";               
        }
?>
```

You were using assigning operator, instead of equal to operator, and secondly check with integer value instead of string.

Comment: Noteworthy: PHP can implicitly convert to number but you are right on this one

Answer (score 1):

The `=` operator assigns the value on the right hand side to the variable on the left.

```
if ($number = '0')
```

This sets `$number` to `0`, which is a *falsy* value, so returns false.

```
elseif ($number = '1')
```

This sets `$number` to `1` which is a *truthy* value, which returns true. This is why your code outputs `1 = 1`.

You need to instead use the [`==` equality operator](http://www.php.net//manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php):

```
if ($number == '0')
   ...
elseif ($number == '1')
   ...
...
```

Answer (score 1):

You are assigning a value to the variable `$number`, you'll need to use the `==` or better `===` to match the number against the value of the variable.

In this case you know `$number` is going to be an integer, it is best practice in PHP to compare as strict as possible, which is the `===` operator. You can use the `==` operator, however the variable will only be loosely matched at that point.

For example a boolean `false` will also match an if-statement containing `if ($number == 0)`, which is not what you want.

Please check the [documentation of PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) to see the full extend of comparison.

Such as the following:

```
<?PHP
    $number = 8;

    // See the triple equal sign here
    if ($number === 0)
        {
           echo $number." = 0";
        }

    // and here
    elseif ($number === 1)
        {
           echo $number." = 1";                
        }

    // and here
    elseif ($number === 2)
        {
           echo $number." = 2";               
        }
    else
        {
           echo $number." > 3";               
        }
?>
```